# DomPDF remove extra space in footer

Tags: php, magento2, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF to generate my pdf file. Now the idea is to create a design that fills the entire page that includes removing the header and footer of the PDF.  Now I added this code

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$html = "";
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    if ($html !== "") {
        $html .= '<div class="page_break"></div>';
    }                       
    $html .= $this->htmlContentPrint($item);
}

$filename= "newpdffile";
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$customPaper = array(0,0,349,499);
$dompdf->setPaper($customPaper, 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream($filename,array("Attachment"=>0));
```

Now it's loading my HTML content almost perfectly. It's just the content is having a white space at the bottom. Like the one below. Note I tried extending the height of the component inside but it's going to the next page already. So basically the height I defined is the max height of the page but somehow a white space is being displayed

[image]

As you can see there's a white space at the bottom which I want to remove. Note this is not an extra space from the loaded HTML as I already checked it and removed the possible spacing and added a css to remove all padding and margin

Comment: Are your elements "high" enough? You said you removed all padding and margin, but if the only reason that the upper port is that high is the image, then the content just isnt longer than it is.

Comment: @ArSeN it's the maximum height I have set. If I added 1px more to the height of the image or other element then the element at the bottom will go to the next page. It's mean that, that's the maximum height I can set